# How to remove styling of React Native Android Button

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a way to remove the styling from a React Native Android `Button` component? I'd like to remove / overwrite the:

- Border Radius
- Drop Shadow
- The 'circle radiating outwards' effect when clicked on.

Comment: why not use touchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback to create a custom button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Button Component accepts no style props, so you are unable to style it.
You could create your own version of the button with any of the *Touchables* components like [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html), or use an external module like [react-native-button](https://github.com/ide/react-native-button)